# How can I access the values of this multiple array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to loop through an array in PHP and extract some values. I am having difficulties in getting the values of the following array like this: `(702,car,707,car2,704car3...)`

This is how my array looks like:

```
[data:protected] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => 702
    [1] => car
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => 707
    [1] => car2
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [0] => 704
    [1] => car3
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [0] => 705
    [1] => car4
  )
  [4] => Array (
    [0] => 708
    [1] => car5
  )
  [5] => Array (
    [0] => 709
    [1] => car6
  )
  [6] => Array (
    [0] => 706
    [1] => car7
  )
  [7] => Array (
    [0] => 703
    [1] => car8
  )
)
```

I've tried this:

```
foreach($result as $resultItem){
   $resultArray[] = $resultItem['n'];
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

But this gives me only the values:

```
   Array ( [0] => 702 [1] => 707 [2] => 704 [3] => 705 [4] => 708 [5] => 709 [6] => 706 [7] => 703 )
```

How do I access the other values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $resultItem) {
    foreach ($resultItem as $resultItemItem) {
        $resultArray[] = $resultItemItem;
    }
}
```

This should do the thrick if I see your array.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the dimension of the array is always 2 you can do it like this

```
foreach($result as $resultItem)
{
    if(is_array($resultItem))
    {
        foreach($resultItem as $resultSubItem)
        {
            $resultArray[] = $resultSubItem;
        }
    }
    else $resultArray[] = $resultItem:
 }
```

If the dimension of the array is unknown and you simply want to flatten the array see this question [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($result));
foreach($it as $v) 
{
    $resultArray[] = $v;
}
```

Comment: The bottom answer is the best indeed. It will fit in every case. Even better then my own proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
foreach($result as $resultItem){
   $resultArray[] = $resultItem[0];
   $resultArray[] = $resultItem[1];
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

Comment: This would work if you're sure that there are only 2 entries in each sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $resultItem){
   $resultArray[] = array(
      $resultItem[0],
      $resultItem[1]
   );
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

you could also do it like this

```
foreach($result as $resultItem){
   $resultArray[$resultItem[0]] = $resultItem[1];
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

this way your array would look like

Array([701] => 'car',[702] => 'car',[703] => 'car')

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach($result as $resultItem){
   $resultArray = array_merge($resultArray,$resultItem);
}
```